# Mapping key and values, adding message in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, key, chat

I have a question about mapping, map key and map values.

I am writing a chat program : I have a problem to add a message. I can't add a message.  That puts me in a empty web page with an error(can't see the number and reason of error)

Can you tell me where is the problem ?

```
// add a message to a chatroom
@RequestMapping(value="/addMessageSalon/{salon}/{pseudo}/{message}", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String addMessageSalon(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("salon") String chatroom, @PathVariable("pseudo") String username, @PathVariable("message") String message) {

    Message mes = null;      
    mes.setMessage(message);      
    mes.setPseudo(username);

    GestionMessages addition = (GestionMessages)request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("gestionMessages");

    Map<String, ArrayList<Message>> resultat = addition.getMessages();

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Message>>> entries = resultat.entrySet().iterator();        

    // iteration
    while(entries.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Message>> entry = entries.next();

        if(!entries.hasNext() && !entry.getKey().contains(chatroom)) {

            // if chatroom does not exist, we give an error
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Chatroom '" + chatroom + "' doesn't exist");        
        }

        if(entry.getKey().contains(chatroom)){     
            ControleurPrincipal.getUsersInDataBase().add(username);                 
            addition.getMessagesSalon(chatroom).add(mes);                
            break;                              
        }                 
    }

    resultat = addition.getMessages();
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific in your question, explain what is the issue, the actual behavior, highlight the part of code that does not work.

Comment: And try to use English including for naming methods, variables, classes. Not everyone here knows French.

Comment: I did it, you are right @AdrianBer

Comment: And you got your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
Message mes = null;      
mes.setMessage(message);
```

This **will** throw a NullPointerException, every time. So either that's the error you're getting, or that is *not* your code.

If that's your actual code, then you need to instantiate Message first, like this:

```
Message mes = new Message();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this

```
if(!entries.hasNext() && !entry.getKey().contains(monSalon)) {
```

you might want to do

```
if(!resultat.contains(monSalon)) {
```

and do it before the `while`.